# node.js can a method be written so it can be called both ways - i.e. with callback or async/await?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

Over the years I created a library of standard methods that I use in my projects. Many of them have callbacks. I recently learnt about promises and async/await to make code read synchronous and like it over the earlier callbacks.

For the ongoing and future projects I'd like to use async/await for my older methods in library. Is it possible to simply add 'async' in front of them and then when I call them I add 'await' to make them promise friendly. Yet at the same time my older projects can use them and call them as callbacks ?

for eg:

```
var checkIfFileExists = function(filename,callback){

    fs.stat(filename, function(err, stat) {

        if(err == null) {

            let jsonObj =   {   'status'        : true,
                                'error'         : false
                            };

        } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {

            console.log( 'File ' + filename + ' does not exists');

            let jsonObj = { 'status'        : false,
                            'error'     :   err
                        };

        } else {

            let jsonObj =   { 'status'        : false,
                                'error'     : err
                            };
        }

        callback(jsonObj);


    });

};
```

for this method can I simply add 'async' like this:

```
var checkIfFileExists = async function(filename,callback){ .... }
```

and then my old projects call it as callbacks:

```
 checkIfFileExists(fileToCheck, function(jsonResponse){
      // do something with response
 });
```

and new projects call it as :

```
let jsonResponse = await checkIfFileExists(fileToCheck);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, even older code can use promises just fine.  Promises can easily be polyfilled in pretty much any version of node.js or the browser and the caller can use `.then()` and `.catch()` just fine.  So, my first argument would be that it's just time to move forward and leave the older callback-style behind.  Using promises doesn't prevent anyone from using your code, it just forces them to move their programming knowledge into the right decade.

If you did want to offer both a callback and promise option in the same interface, then, you cannot just place `async` on the function and have everything work.  That's not what `async` does.  It doesn't have that level of super-power.  Plus, if you want compatibility with an older version of node.js, then that version may not support `async` either.

The usual way of making something that can be called either way is to detect whether the callback is passed and the code adapts based on whether it was passed or not, returning a promise that is hooked up to the completion of your code if no callback was passed or using the callback if it was passed.

So, if you had an interface `checkIfFileExists(...)`, you could use it either like this:

```
 // with callback
 checkIfFileExists("myfile.txt", function(err, exists) {
     if (err) {
         console.log(err);
     } else {
         console.log(exists);
     }
 });

 // with promise
 checkIfFileExists("myfile.txt").then(function(exists) {
     console.log(exists);
 }).catch(function(err) {
     console.log(err);
 });
```

And, here's an implementation:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const promisify = require('util').promisify;

function makePromisify(fn) {
    if (fn._p) {
       return fn._p;
    } else {
       fn._p = promisify(fn);
       return fn._p;
    }
}

// if not called with callback, then returns a promise
function checkIfFileExists(filename, callback) {
    if (!callback) {
        return makePromisify(checkIfFileExists)(filename);
    } else {
        fs.stat(filename, function(err, stats) {
           if (err) {
               if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                   callback(null, false);
               } else {
                   callback(err);
               }
           } else {
              callback(null, true);
           }
        });
    }
}
```

This implementation uses `util.promisify()` (added in node v8.0) to make a promisified version of the callback interface automatically for you.  If you want to support versions of node.js old enough that `util.promisify()` doesn't even exist, then that can be built manually in a few lines of code too.

For efficiency reasons, it caches the promisified version of the function upon first use as the `._p` property on the called function so on subsequent calls, it can use the exact same promisified version of the function.

Note, I would prefer a design that optimized first for the promise interface because that's the more likely use going forward as that is the future of the Javascript language and should be the more common use.  But, for a function like this, you'd want to use the `fs.promises` interface to the `fs` module and that assumes at least node v10.0.

---

If you can assume at laest node v10, then this gets a little simpler with the `fs.promises` interface and it's more streamlined for promise usage:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

// if not called with callback, then returns a promise
function checkIfFileExists(filename, callback) {

    async function _checkIfFilesExists(filename) {
        try {
            await fsp.stat(filename);
            return true;
        } catch(err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                return false;
            } else {
                throw err;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!callback) {
        return _checkIfFileExists(filename);
    } else {
        _checkIfFileExists(filename).then(result => {
           callback(null, result);
       }).catch(callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome !! Thank you! When I started reading your asnwer, I realized that I could have easily checked if callback was passed. But then I see the methods you've recommended and they look like the way to go. These will work perfectly for my libraries. Thanks again !

Comment: @Curious101 - I just fixed a little error in the `makePromisify()` function so make sure you get the latest version of that.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00.

Answer (score 2):

There are various libraries for "promisifying" by basically wrapping existing functions that use the standard callback parameters in a way that returns promises.  That might be useful to you.

For example:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promisify

```
const {promisify} = require("es6-promisify");
const checkIfFileExistsPromise = promisify(checkFileIfExists);

const exists = await checkIfFileExistsPromise(...);
```

Also note that `fs` has a promise-based API built right into Node.js these days:  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

Comment: Thanks Brad. Appreciate the prompt response. I'll look into this as well. This may be suitable for some of my older methods. I did mark @jfriend00 's answer as correct as it is quite comprehensive.